# missing equivalent words

Tags: single-word-requests

I note the discussion of the lack of female equivalent for uxorious.  Is there any equivalent for avuncular?

Answer (score 0):

Female version of avuncular (well disposed to youth and inexperience in the manner of an uncle):

[materteral](https://www.yourdictionary.com/materteral)
Adjective

(comparative more materteral, superlative most materteral)

> Pertaining to, or in the manner of, an aunt; feminine version of
>   avuncular

yourdictionary.com

[Google trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=marterteral&geo=US) shows no usage data.